How to set FontSize in Avalonia UI specifically only for the Android version of the application?
I'm writing a cross-platform application using the Avalonia UI Community Toolkit. and it turned out that one of my TextBlocks
does not fit on the screen when launched on the phone. how to set FontSize for this TextBlock was specifically for the android version. for example for the Desktop version this is 24, and for Android it is 20
I tried to do this using ChatGPT but nothing worked
here is an example
axaml markup

  <Border Grid.Row="0" Background="#2576f7" Height="28" MaxHeight="28">
  <Grid>
  <Button Background="Transparent" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Content="Back" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold" Command="{Binding NavigateToSelectItemMorphologyTestPageCommand}">
  <Button.Styles>
  <Style Selector="Button:pointerover /template/ ContentPresenter">
  <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
  </Style>
  </Button.Styles>
  </Button>
  <TextBlock x:Name="HeaderText" Text="long text that doesn't fit on the page " FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="24" FontWeight="Bold" TextAlignment="Center"/>
  </Grid>
  </Border>

and just the text size of 24 does not fit on the page on the Telophane screen, but everything is fine on the computer screen.

This is what ChatGPT advised me.

...ViewModel


[ObservableProperty]
 private bool isAndroid;

 public ...ViewModel()
 {
 IsAndroid = RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Create("ANDROID"));
 }

and change the markup

<UserControl.Resources>
 <Style x:Key="HeaderTextStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
 <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Arial" />
 <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="24" />
 <Style.Triggers>
 <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsAndroid}" Value="True">
 <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20" />
 </DataTrigger>
 </Style.Triggers>
 </Style>
 </UserControl.Resources>

 <Grid Background="#ffdadada">
 <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
 <Grid>
 <Grid.RowDefinitions>
 <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
 <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
 </Grid.RowDefinitions>

 <Border Grid.Row="0" Background="#2576f7" Height="28" MaxHeight="28">
 <Grid>
 <Button Background="Transparent" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Content="Back" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold" Command="{Binding NavigateToSelectItemTestRussianPageCommand}">
 <Button.Styles>
 <Style Selector="Button:pointerover /template/ ContentPresenter">
 <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
 </Style>
 </Button.Styles>
 </Button>
 <TextBlock Text="long text that doesn't fit on the page" FontWeight="Bold" TextAlignment="Center" Style="{StaticResource HeaderTextStyle}"/>
 </Grid>
 </Border>


but there were a lot of errors
1.
Error (active) AXN0002 XamlX.XamlParseException: Unable to resolve type DataTrigger from namespace https://github.com/avaloniaui Line 14, position 6.
2. Error (active) CS0103 The name 'InitializeComponent' does not exist in the current context

but I couldn’t fix them and I also couldn’t find a way to do it differently

sorry for my english as it is not my native language

You are better off scaling it based off the view size.  Android isn't a fixed screen size, it can be anything from a tiny phone to a 10" tablet or more.  Get your view's current size and make a decision on font based on that.

You can cover your elements into Viewbox and if view bounds is too restricted - viewbox will scale down it's content.
Read more at official Avalonia Documentation https://docs.avaloniaui.net/docs/reference/controls/viewbox
